# Add Site Column as Managed Property to CSWP Display

Tags: managed-property, cswp

Hmm, I have a content type for News with a site column called "Abstract" (multi line text).  I have added the column as a Managed Property in the search schema and selected it for the Property mapping in the Content Search Web Part.

But it will not display the value.  What could I be missing?

Bismarck

Answer (score 0):

One thing that MAY be an issue is the Item Display Template that you're using on the CSWP. Also, with the Abstract multi-line text field there could be an issue with the type of text to allow - Plain, Rich text, Enhanced.